# Storage/Traffic usage for different features (chat,content...)

Tags: quickblox

since Quickblox plans have a storage/Traffic limitation lets say 50Gb.  I am trying to figure out the Storage/Traffic usage of the features, chat, user, custom objects, content and video in terms of the limitation (I am calling it usage charge)

1) Chat - Is there a traffic usage charge for every chat message sent/received?

2) Custom Object - I assume to store objects there is a storage usage charge but is there a traffic usage charge each time I access the objects (API calls should be free)?

3) Content - I assume to store content there is a storage usage charge but is there a traffic usage charge each time I access the content (API calls should be free)?

4) Video - supposed to be free?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

API calls are free, you're right

10 GB storage: it's only about Content files (not Custom Objects records/Chat messages/Users etc.)

10 GB traffic: actually download/upload files from/to Content module produces the main traffic. API calls - it's really small amount of traffic, don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is the data transferred during API calls part of traffic usage. My app updates the location of up to 20 users every 5 minutes, so 20 user/location (about 200 bytes per user) info is obtained from the server, is this part of traffic usage?

Comment: No, it isn't, API calls - it's really small amount of traffic, don't worry about it.